# pass json id from one table view controller into another table view controller in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, segue

I already new in swift 3 and objetive c, right now I am stuck into how can I pass the id of each row to another table view controller when the user tap in the row the user want to go.

Here is the json data firstFile:

```
[
{"id_categoria":"1","totalRows":"323","nombre_categoria":"Cirug\u00eda"},
{"id_categoria":"2","totalRows":"312","nombre_categoria":"Med Interna"},
{"id_categoria":"3","totalRows":"6","nombre_categoria":"Anatomia"},
{"id_categoria":"4","totalRows":"24","nombre_categoria":"Anestesiologia"},
...]
```

Here is my first table view controller:

```
import UIKit

class CatMedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBAction func volver(_ sender: Any) { }
    @IBOutlet weak var listaCategoria: UITableView!

    var fetchedCategoria = [Categoria]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        listaCategoria.dataSource = self
        parseData()
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedCategoria.count
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt IndexPath: IndexPath) ->
        UITableViewCell {
            let cell = listaCategoria.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

            cell?.textLabel?.text = fetchedCategoria[IndexPath.row].esp
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = fetchedCategoria [IndexPath.row].totalRows

            return cell!
    }


    func parseData() {
        let url = "http://www.url.com/firstFile.php"  //in json format
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil) {
                print("Error")
            }
            else {
                do {
                    let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray
                    //print(fetchedData)

                    for eachFetchedCategoria in fetchedData {
                        let eachCategoria = eachFetchedCategoria as! [String : Any]
                        let nombre_categoria = eachCategoria["nombre_categoria"] as! String
                        let totalRows = eachCategoria["totalRows"] as! String
                        let id_categoria = eachCategoria["id_categoria"] as! String

                        self.fetchedCategoria.append(Categoria(nombre_categoria: nombre_categoria, totalRows: totalRows, id_categoria: id_categoria))
                    }
                    //print(self.fetchedCategoria)

                    self.listaCategoria.reloadData()
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error 2")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

class Categoria {
    var nombre_categoria : String
    var totalRows : String
    var id_categoria : String

    init(nombre_categoria : String, totalRows : String, id_categoria : String) {
        self.nombre_categoria = nombre_categoria
        self.totalRows = totalRows
        self.id_categoria = id_categoria
    }
}
```

So I need pass the **id_categoria String** into the another table view to show the data for the id selected previously...here I don't know how to do it...I have the json file waiting for the id selected previously..but I don't know how to catch it into the url

Here the second table view:

```
import UIKit

class EspMedVC: UITableViewController {

    var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

    var EspecialidadArray  = [String]()

    @IBAction func volver(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        get_data_from_url("http://www.url.com/secondFile.php?id=") // Here I need to put the id_categoria String in json format
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TableData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
    {
        let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
                return
            }
            self.extract_json(data!)
        })

        task.resume()
    }


    func extract_json(_ data: Data)
    {
        let json: Any?

        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }

        guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else
        {
            return
        }


        if let nombre_especialidad = json as? NSArray
        {
            for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
            {
                if let nombre_esp_obj = nombre_especialidad[i] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let nombre_especialidad = nombre_esp_obj["subesp"] as? String
                    {
                        if let totalRows = nombre_esp_obj["totalRows"] as? String
                        {
                            TableData.append(nombre_especialidad + " [" + totalRows + "]")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.do_table_refresh()})
    }

    func do_table_refresh()
    {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the second table view in a different View Controller?

Comment: @Pochi Yes, the first one is: **CatMedVC** and the second: **EspMedVC**

Comment: And how do you move to EspMedVC?

Comment: @Pochi, well to be honest, I only link the segue CatMedVC to the EspMedVC in main.storyboard

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough guide, please search for the methods in the documentation or here at other questions inside stackoverflow.

1) Add a variable inside your **EspMedVC** that will hold the "id_categoria String" that should be displayed.

2) Add a variable inside your **CatMedVC** that will hold the "id_categoria String" that the user selected.

3) Implement the "didSelectRow" delegate method from your tableview inside the "CatMedVC", inside this method you should set the variable set on step 2.

4) Implement the "prepareForSegue" method inside your CatMedVC, inside the the implementation you should retrieve the destination VC, cast it to "EspMedVC" and set the variable from step 1.

5) On the "viewDidLoad" from **EspMedVC** you can now use the variable set on step 2 to query your JSON and update the table view accordingly.